# Extract partial Json from response as per request

Tags: c#, json

I am writing a web api action which accepts a string request (json) and returns the response as requested in the request json.

To elaborate it further:
The request is:

```
{
    "Id":"",
   "Wells":[{"WellNumber":""}],
   "ExternalKey":""

}
```

The data that I get from database is

```
[
    {
        "Id": "J.16.002219",
        "Wells": [
            {
                "WellNumber": "63000008",
                "WellName": "Well One Desc",
                "ExternalKey": "ZW",
                "Job_Id": "J.16.002219",
                "HoleSections": null
            }
        ],
        "ExternalKey": null
    }
]
```

What I want to return as a response of web api method is a subset of data from database and should look like

```
[
    {
        "Id": "J.16.002219",
        "Wells": [
            {
                "WellNumber": "63000008",                
            }
        ],
        "ExternalKey": null
    }
]
```

basically I don't want to return the data that has not been requested.

Comment: Are the fields in input request fixed/constant or they can vary across requests? e.g. first request had 3 fields and then the next request has 4 fields and so on.

Comment: yes they can change.

Comment: There is one thing that I noticed during my final json x-path based implementation - The output string that you have mentioned in your post starts with a square bracket which makes it an array at the root itself. I can understand that the fields in input can vary but how come the formats are different. The output returned from DB is an array while the input you received wasn't. You might want to correct it if that's the case.

Comment: Yes you are right in pointing out that, The reason is that I will have couple of response objects from DB and each needs to be trimmed down as per request and sent back as collection

Comment: Ok. Got it. In that case you can still use the current logic but it is just you will have to process each json array element one by one and then rejoin the output elements to create the array for sending back the response.

Comment: yeah. that what I am doing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! You can call the `GetOnlyRequestedData` from your web API after you have received the response from your database. I have demonstrated a sample on how to call it in the main method. You will have to add a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package in your project for all this to work.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputRequest = "{\"Id\":\"\",\"Wells\":[{\"WellNumber\":\"\"}],\"ExternalKey\":\"\"}";
            var valueObtainedFromDb =
                "{\"Id\":\"J.16.002219\",\"Wells\":[{\"WellNumber\":\"63000008\",\"WellName\":\"Well One Desc\",\"ExternalKey\":\"ZW\",\"Job_Id\":\"J.16.002219\",\"HoleSections\":null}],\"ExternalKey\":null}";
            var filteredOutput = GetOnlyRequestedData(inputRequest, valueObtainedFromDb);
            Console.WriteLine(filteredOutput);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static JToken GetOnlyRequestedData(string jsonFilter, string targetData)
        {
            var jToken = JToken.Parse(jsonFilter);
            JToken outputToken = JToken.Parse(targetData);
            List<string> fieldsToBePreserved = new List<string>();
            GetFlattenedPropertyList(jToken, ref fieldsToBePreserved);
            removeFields(outputToken, fieldsToBePreserved);
            return outputToken;
        }


        private static void GetFlattenedPropertyList(JToken jObject, ref List<string> fieldsToBePreserved)
        {
            JContainer container = jObject as JContainer;
            if (container == null) return;

            foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
            {
                JProperty p = el as JProperty;
                if (p != null)
                {
                    fieldsToBePreserved.Add(p.Name + p.Path);
                }
                GetFlattenedPropertyList(el, ref fieldsToBePreserved);    
            }
        }

        private static void removeFields(JToken token, List<string> fields)
        {
            JContainer container = token as JContainer;
            if (container == null) return;

            List<JToken> removeList = new List<JToken>();
            foreach (JToken el in container.Children())
            {
                JProperty p = el as JProperty;
                if (p != null && !fields.Contains(p.Name + p.Path))
                {
                    removeList.Add(el);
                }
                removeFields(el, fields);
            }

            foreach (JToken el in removeList)
            {
                el.Remove();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It works at level one but does not go inside the array to remove the properties. Here Well is array type in request, but p.Type will be Property so the loop never goes inside.

Comment: I was able to get the exact output as you have asked in your post. I was able to get rid of various properties like `Job_Id` and `HoleSections` which are not a level 1, they are inside `Wells` property instead.

Comment: Please note `GetFlattenedPropertyList` has been called recursively to get the list of all the nodes which are to be preserved and `removeFields` has also been called recursively to scan through children and children of children to get the nodes which are to be dropped by comparing them against the preservation list I created at first hand.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but p.Type in `p.Type == JTokenType.Array` will be of type Property even when the value is Array so it is not going inside the if and hence not calling it recursively. I am trying to do a check in p.Value.Type to check if it is Array and send p.Value as JContainer, but it seems to be not working.

Comment: Yep. Got it now. I'll try fixing this.

Comment: You should be good now. I've updated the code. I'm sorry it took a while as it was my first exercise on Json parsing. I ended up using JObject to fix that array related issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort. I also kind of achieved in similar way. There is still one problem that if a property is requested at level 1 but it is also present at level 2 in response, The program will return it at all the levels.

Comment: Then you will have maintain a dictionary instead of the list where the key would be the node name to be preserved and its x-path as value. At the point where we are doing the removal part then we should match the node name as well as the x-path.

Comment: Updated the source code to handle JSON x-path. Now if same named nodes are present at several locations then only that node will be preserved which has same x-path as the one received in the input. In your case `ExternalKey` node present inside `Wells` node in DB response will not be preserved. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize and return a subset of the result from the database one way could be to create a model that represents- and contains only the data you want to send back. e.g

```
public class ResponseModel
{
   public string Id { get; set;}
   public List<Well> Wells { get; set;}
   public string ExternalKey { get; set;}
}

public class Well
{
   public string WellNumber { get; set;}
}
```

You can then serialize this type to json and send back.

Comment: The request can change, so, in one request user can ask for well and in other just the Id. So, we can not create a concrete class.